# Change installed language in quite-mode

Tags: powershell, install4j

I'm trying to change the installed language with install4j, according to the documentation the parameter I should use is:

```
-Dinstall4j.language=[ISO code]
```

I'd like it to install in English but it keeps installing it in Swedish, the iso-codes I've tried is: en and En_us.

This is how I add the parameter, is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

```
> .\Setup_64bit.exe -Dinstall4j.language=en
```

Environment: Windows 7, Powershell, Install4j 5.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I found to solve this was installing it locally on a OS with the correct language selection. Then I went to the .install4j folder(which can be found in the same folder where your application is installed) and inside this folder there is a **response.varfile**. The .varfile can be put next to the installation .exe, and if given the same name as the .exe file but with .varfile the installer will automatically use this response-file to select language! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `-Dinstall4j.language=en` is correct, but if you have already installed it before, a "Load a response file" action in your project will load the response file from previous installation and override the selection on the command line.